# how to write asp.net minimal api optional parameter?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-minimal-apis

I wrote an endpoint which accepts MediaParams object which extends another param class and together they act like a wrapper for parameters and look like this:

```
public class MediaParams : PaginationParams
    {
        public string OrderBy { get; set; } = "title";
        public string SearchTerm { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Genres { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
    public class PaginationParams
    {
        private const int MaxPageSize = 50;
        public int PageNumber { get; set; } = 1;
        private int _pageSize = 6;

        public int PageSize
        {
            get => _pageSize;
            set => _pageSize = value > MaxPageSize ? MaxPageSize : value;
        }
    }
```

As you may notice I also assigned a default values for each property as I want to make them optional, my endpoint

```
app.MapGet("/media/getby", async (
    [AsParameters] MediaParams pa,
    IMediator mediator,
    HttpContext context) =>
{
    var mediaListDto = await mediator.Send(new GetMediaByParamsQuery(pa));

    if (mediaListDto is not { Count: > 0 })
    {
        return Results.NotFound("No media was found by these params.");
    }
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Pagination", JsonSerializer.Serialize(mediaListDto.MetaData));
    return Results.Ok(mediaListDto);
});
```

Now it works ok, but only if I specify every single property in my uri like this:

> serveraddress/media/getby?OrderBy=rating&SearchTerm=pal&Genres=Drama&PageNumber=1&PageSize=10

Could someone help me to rewrite the logic so I could use these params individually to override default values, or not use at all to keep default values? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `[FromQuery]` attribute instead of `[AsParameters]`?

Comment: @RafalKozlowski ofc, It throws  "An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.InvalidOperationException: No public static bool MediaParams.TryParse(string, out MediaParams) method found for pa."

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `AsParameter` by default requires all properties and when it deserialises it skips the default values because it uses `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject` that instantiates an object but without invocation of its constructor and field initializers (because of performance purposes as this class & method should be used for serialisation/deserialisation).

When I changed your models to the following code, it started doing its job:

```
public class MediaParams : PaginationParams
    {
        [DefaultValue("title")]
        public string? OrderBy { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(" ")]
        public string? SearchTerm { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(" ")]
        public string? Genres { get; set; }
    }

    public class PaginationParams
    {
        private const int MaxPageSize = 50;

        [DefaultValue(1)]
        public int? PageNumber { get; set; }
        
        [DefaultValue(6)]
        public int? PageSize { get; set; }
    }
```

Sadly, when `DefaultValue` has a value of `"" (string.Empty)` passed, it converts it to `null`. If you play around with setters and logic there to prevent assigning nulls, this should do the work for you.

Comment: Thank you for response, unfortunately it didn't work for me as it did set all values to null for some reason, so I ended up removing all params from the endpoint and added a class to read params from the the request just like "if (context.Request.Query.ContainsKey("OrderBy"))" and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a class that reads the request and "assembles" a parameters object or keeps default values, I also removed default values from Parameter classes like MediaParams and PaginationParams, and also removed the nullability from properties of these classes

```
public static class QueryHelper
{
    private const string OrderByDefaultValue = "title";
    private const string SearchTermDefaultValue = "";
    private const int PageNumberDefaultValue = 1;
    private const int PageSizeDefaultValue = 6;


    public static MediaParams GetMediaParams(HttpContext context)
    {
        var mediaParams = new MediaParams
        {
            OrderBy = OrderByDefaultValue,
            SearchTerm = SearchTermDefaultValue,
            Genres = null,
            PageNumber = PageNumberDefaultValue,
            PageSize = PageSizeDefaultValue
        };
        //other parameters
        return mediaParams;
    }
}
```

In endpoint I am calling this class like this

```
var pa = QueryHelper.GetMediaParams(context);
```